# Best way to keep values?

Tags: android

I'd like to create app with 3 months exercise plan. There will be around 30 exercises to do every day but time is growing. What is best way to keep values of minutes in every exercises and which one exercises you should do today. Im using Firebase in this project but im not sure about optimalization because there will be much datas just from exercises. Every exercises has photo how to do this, time and description and I need to store the length of the exercise for each day so I do not know if this is a good solution.

Comment: If you are not going to do anything with the data generated by the user, you can better use SQLite to store data locally that can be access by that user only. If you are going to have some advanced features like sharing, competing with other users, you probably need a backend to serve data. In that case firebase is the best option. Also to note that firebase have inbuilt offline capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a relational Database like MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB to store the data server-side.

If you want to persist the data on the Android-side of things use SQLite https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

If you application doesn't require online connectivity all the time, a nice idea would be to be able to sync the server DB with the android DB for offline usage.